# Google Sheets -- Dynamically change cell reference

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Need a little help:

I have a link in J5 that is `=DataIn!O2`

I need cell O5 to link to `DataIn!O243`, however, I need to do it dymanically as other columns will need to use this as well. I need to be able to copy J5 into O5, T5, etc having the `DataIn!O2` increase by 241 each time.

For example when I copy J5 which is `=DataIn!O2` ,

```
O5 would be =DataIn!O246
T5 would be =DataIn!O487
```

Then copy into next row the values would be :

```
J6 =DataIn!O3
O6 =DataIn!O247
T6 =DataIn!O488
```

I tried `=INDIRECT("DataIn!O"&2+241)` but that did not work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome. Would you please share a copy of your spreadsheet, and include an example of a successful outcome.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `COLUMN()` function.

This gets the column of the current cell.

Your function then can be `INDIRECT("A"&(<X>), TRUE)`, where `<X>` needs to be a custom formula based on your description.

As an example:

- Placing this formula on `C1` and dragging it to the side (`D1`, `E1`, `F1`, etc)
- Starting values on `A1`
- Getting every 4 values (`A1`, `A5`, `A9`, `A13`, etc)

My `<X>` is `<starting number>`+(COLUMN()-`<starting column number>`)*`<value interval>`.

Translating to: `1+(COLUMN()-3)*4`.